# Node (weight) containing it's own NodeIndex

Tags: rust, petgraph

I want to create Nodes (weights) which contain its own `NodeIndex`

```
struct Node {
  index: NodeIndex,
  ...
}
```

However, in order to get the `NodeIndex`, I need to call [`graph.add_node(node)`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html#method.add_node) which requires a fully constructed `Node`.

Is there a way I can accomplish this without having to use `Option<NodeIndex>`?

Comment: You can use a [raw pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html) which can be NULL, but it's not idiomatic or recommended in this case.

Comment: What's `graph`? Can you change `add_node`?

Comment: @cafce25 It's a method from petgraph, added link.  I cannot change `add_node` but I could be unaware of a similar method that generates a `NodeIndex` without requiring a constructed `weight`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change my design such that this is no longer necessary, and probably for the better.

The point of using petgraph (at least in my case) is to create a graph like structure without having to deal with self-referential types (see [this post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-we-teach-people-about-self-referential-types/65362/2) for more details).

This only works if petgraph's `Graph` has (sole?) ownership of the nodes.  Once you add your node to the graph via `graph.add_node(node)`, it returns you the `NodeIndex` which will be your handle towards that `node` in the future (think of it as a pointer).

So storing the `NodeIndex` inside the `Node` makes as much sense as storing the pointer to the object inside the object itself.  In my case, it was a symptom of a misuse and misunderstanding of petgraph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying it's a good idea, but [`NodeIndex` implements `Default`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/graph/struct.NodeIndex.html#impl-Default-for-NodeIndex%3CIx%3E), so you can fill it initially with the default value, and once you call `add_node()` and get the real index, index the graph with it and overwrite the node data.